# change default login path in asp .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

how to change the default path of the login page?

I have tried

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/e-tol/Login";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
```

but when it runs, we still can use /Login , I need to prevent users from login by using /Login only

I have read many answers that are similar to my case but still do not work

**UPDATE**

This is my action method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string message)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;

        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectAfterAuthenticated();

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        return View();
    }

private IActionResult RedirectAfterAuthenticated()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var role = identity.Claims
            .Where(i => i.Type == "IdRole")
            .Select(i => i.Value)
            .SingleOrDefault();
      
        switch (role)
        {
            case null:
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            default:
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password, string ReturnUrl)
        {
            var getUsername = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Username == username);
            var getPassword = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Password == password);

            if (getUsername != null && getPassword != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Convert.ToString(getUsername.IdUser)),
                    new Claim("Nama", getUsername.Nama),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, getUsername.Username),
                    new Claim("IdRole", Convert.ToString(getUsername.IdRole)),
                };

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                                
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                               new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

                return Redirect(ReturnUrl == null ? "/Home" : ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {                
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new RouteValueDictionary(new { message = "Username / Password Salah" }));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have tried to add the route attribute like [Route(/e-tol/Login")] in your action?Can you provide your action code?

Comment: @XinranShen Yes I have, but my login page returns Not Found

Comment: Hi @Himawan Sandhi,Do you have changed something in `Startup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't show the Controller catalog and I don't konw what is the corresponding method of `/e-tol/Login` , So I write a demo to show the situation:

I add  `[Route("/e-tol/Login")]` to `Login` action in `AccountController` controller

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Create() 
    { 
         return View();
    }
}
```

**AccountController**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
       
        [Route("/e-tol/Login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        
    }
```

**StartUp**

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/e-tol/Login");
```

**Then,When I want to Log in ,I can only use `/e-tol/Login`,When i use `/Login` ,it will report a 404 error.**

[image]

Comment: thanks for showing the demo and answering my question, this was exactly what I wanted, I think I need to check again my Startup.cs, maybe something wrong there

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. Thanks.